# Change Developer Facebook API version

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have to use fql since Facebook graph are not able to retrieve Facebook Page past events.

In developer page, the dashboard shows the the API version is v2.3

[image]

No matter what i try in FB.init() by using v2.0. It's still doesn't work with `fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher`
Does anyone know how to change the API version in the App page itself? Because whatever version I pass in FB.init, it will be upgraded automatically to v2.3.

Comment: Your app will use at least the latest API version that was available at the time your app was created – you can not “downgrade” any lower than that.

Comment: so, there is no workaround for this?

Comment: Correct. You can not downgrade

Comment: is there a way to get past events without using fql?